# Como colocar .htacces en Ghost

Tags: javascript, nodejs, .htaccess

estoy tratando de agregar la compresión gzip a mi proyecto de [Ghost.org](http://Ghost.org) pero no eh podido, utilizo ghost-cli y nginx para servir, pero en sites-available genera un proxy que manda a un node que corre en localhost, esta es la configuración del nginx

```
server {

server_name latribu.mx www.latribu.mx;
root /var/www/latribu.mx/html/system/nginx-root;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;

}

location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
}

client_max_body_size 50m;

listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/latribu.mx/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/latribu.mx/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
if ($host = latribu.mx) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

if ($host = www.latribu.mx) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name latribu.mx www.latribu.mx;
return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Cómo puedo agregar un .htacces a mi proyecto

Answer (score 1):

`.htaccess` es un archivo de configuración de apache, para nginx hay directivas en la configuración, por ejemplo:

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
gzip            on;
gzip_min_length 1000;
gzip_proxied    expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_types      text/plain application/xml;
```

Luego reinicias el servidor

`$ sudo service nginx restart`

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html